# Some questions about radical ideals

Tags: proof-verification, commutative-algebra

An ideal $I$ is said to be radical if $I=\sqrt{I}$. I have 2 questions.

Is it correct ?

> > $I$ is a radical ideal. $\iff$ If $x^n\in I$ for some $n$, then $x\in I$

$\text{}$
Is it correct ?

> > Let $J$ be a radical ideal containing $I$. Then $\sqrt{I}\subseteq J$. In other words, $\sqrt{I}$ is the smallest radical ideal containing $I$.

Proof:

Let $x\in\sqrt{I}\implies x^n\in I\subseteq J$.
Hence $x\in\sqrt{J}=J$. Thus  $\sqrt{I}\subseteq J.$

Comment: Yes: these two things are correct.

Comment: @random_guy these  are correct. but u can add a short proof to the 1st question too.